# How to read the i2c adapter class (e.g. I2C_CLASS_DDC) from userspace (linux i2c-dev)?

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, linux-device-driver, i2c

Outside of Laptops, changing e.g. brightness of monitors requires DDC/CI. This is best done in userspace, I believe. Loading `i2c-dev` (kernel module) gives access to i2c-buses under `/dev/i2c-<number>`. Unfortunately not just monitors supporting DDC/CI have i2c-buses and it is far from ideal to read/write on unrelated buses, while trying to find which connects to what.

It seems that i2c bus adapter drivers already categorize their buses: e.g. I2C_CLASS_DDC for exactly what I’m looking for.

Is there any way to see the adapter class of a `i2c-dev` device?

(Or equally good: any way to match the device I want to talk to for DDC/CI from X11 workspaces or similar?)

Answer (score 0):

You can try to look at ddccontrol:

**ddccontrol -p**

This utility scan I2Cs and somehow detects which are connected to monitors.
You can examine it's source code and find solution.

P.S.
This may be not an answer, but, sorry, I have not enough "reputation" to write a comment.

Comment: It tries a read-write operation on every bus using `ioctl(fd, I2C_RDWR, ...)`. That should work with every i2c bus with a slave listening on 0x50. `ddcutil` is a smarter: it uses `ioctl(fd, I2C_FUNCS, ...) to check if the bus in question is not a smbus. (Those are very unlikely DDC/CI.)